# SlideUp close button in expanded div does not respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking for an expandable portfolio solution in jquery and came across a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/XvCTC/) that I liked, except for it missing a close button for the expanded section. 
So I tried adding a button with a simple slideUp() jquery function in an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antonestlund/XvCTC/224/) but the button just does not work. The most curious thing about it is that I tried to place the exact same button outside of the div and there it works like a charm. I have also tried and failed in fixing the problem by changing the close function logic with this() and parent() for the button that is inside the expanded element.

Markup:

```
      <div id="portfolio">
<a class="close"> close </a> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="item" data-rel="0">1</div>
    <div class="item" data-rel="1">2</div>
    <div class="item" data-rel="2">3</div>
</div>
<div class="details"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item" data-rel="3">4</div>
    <div class="item" data-rel="4">5</div>
    <div class="item" data-rel="5">6</div>
</div>
<div class="details"></div>
<ul id="portfolio-details">
    <li>
    <a class="close"> close </a> 
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
    </li>
    <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
    <li>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</li>
    <li>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
    <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
    <li>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var Portfolio = {
Elements: {

    items: $('div.item', '#portfolio'),
    details: $('#portfolio-details', '#portfolio')

},

fn: {

    select: function() {

        Portfolio.Elements.items.each(function() {

            var $item = $(this);
            var $row = $item.parent();
            var $details = $row.next('div.details');
            var $li = $('li', Portfolio.Elements.details);
            var $close = $('.close');


            $item.click(function() {

                $('div.details').hide();
                $details.empty();
                var $html = $li.eq($item.data('rel')).html();
                $details.html($html).slideDown(600);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 0).animate({
                    scrollTop: $details.offset().top
                }, 300);

            });
            $close.click(function() {
                    $details.slideUp();
            });
        });
    }
}
};

Portfolio.fn.select();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the binding of click function on `$('.close')`

```
$('.portfolio').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $details.slideUp();
})
```

Hope, that helps. Not sure though!